# Why Docker compose takes too long to build in windows?

Tags: docker

Why docker compose takes too long to **begin** building an image?
Docker waits ~10 minutes until it began. There is not node_modules or big files in my images.

- My network is not slow.
- I have no antivirus or firewall.

When I add the `verbose` flag I can the see log:

```
$docker-compose --verbose -f .docker/docker-compose.my.yml build

compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: .\.docker/docker-compose.my.yml
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['C:\\Users\\user\\.docker\\config.json', 'C:\\Users\\user\\.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Found file at path: C:\Users\user\.docker\config.json
docker.auth.load_config: Found 'auths' section
docker.auth.parse_auth: Auth data for 00000.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com is absent. Client might be using a credentials store instead.
docker.auth.parse_auth: Auth data for https://index.docker.io/v1/ is absent. Client might be using a credentials store instead.
docker.auth.load_config: Found 'credsStore' section
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/version HTTP/1.1" 200 560
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
docker-py version: 3.6.0
CPython version: 3.6.6
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localnpipe
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: Platform={'Name': 'Docker Engine - Community'}, Components=[{'Name': 'Engine', 'Version': '18.09.1', 'Details': {'ApiVersion': '1.39', 'Arch': 'amd64', 'BuildTime': '2019-01-09T19:41:49.000000000+00:00', 'Experimental': 'false', 'GitCommit': '4c52b90', 'GoVersion': 'go1.10.6', 'KernelVersion': '4.9.125-linuxkit', 'MinAPIVersion': '1.12', 'Os': 'linux'}}], Version=18.09.1, ApiVersion=1.39, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=4c52b90, GoVersion=go1.10.6, Os=linux, Arch=amd64, KernelVersion=4.9.125-linuxkit, BuildTime=2019-01-09T19:41:49.000000000+00:00
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('docker_default')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.25/networks/docker_default HTTP/1.1" 404 47
compose.service.build: Building app-www
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- (path='\\\\?\\C:\\myapp', tag='docker_app-www', rm=True, forcerm=False, pull=False, nocache=False, dockerfile='./.docker/Dockerfile-app-www', cache_from=None, labels=None, buildargs={}, network_mode=None, target=None, shmsize=None, extra_hosts=None, container_limits={'memory': None}, gzip=False, isolation=None, platform=None)
```

After ~10 min, it's start to build the image.

**.docker/docker-compose.my.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app-www:
    image: 00000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/app-www:latest
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./.docker/Dockerfile-app-www
```

**.docker/Dockerfile-app-www**

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./dist/myapp .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Are you able to make a small docker-compose yaml make up of public images or dockerfiles you can share that you could make public here? This will help anyone looking at this greatly, otherwise people can only take guesses like your network is slow or the windows filesystem is bad, or it's getting stuck in antivirus etc.

Comment: updated my question :)

Comment: I think the problem is the "context: ../". This means that the complete parent folder (where your docker-compose.yaml is) is sent to the docker daemon. How large is it (recursive)? How many files are in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the build context, as stated in the docs this is sent to the docker daemon which could end up being a large transfer.
From the docs (emphasis mine)

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#context

> When the value supplied is a relative path, it is interpreted as relative to the location of the Compose file. **This directory is also the build context that is sent to the Docker daemon**.

The way to tell would be to point to a folder with nothing in it and a simplified Dockerfile and see if that starts faster.

Comment: Yeah it's works. but now I need to change my output dir from dist to .docker/app folder or just copy the files. Because I got error: `failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context:`

Comment: You do need everything used by the dockerfile to be reachable from the build context. In your case ensure the content in `dist/myapp` is in the context and nothing else. The key to keeping it fast is keeping the context as small as possible.